# GCC 10.1.0 on macOS Big Sur

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, cross-compiling, gnu

I'm trying to Compile GCC 10.1.0 on macOS Big Sur with the new arm powered Mac. Due of the lack of tutorials for compiling on Big Sur, I decided to compile as if on Catalina using [this tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/10/12/compiling-gcc-macos/). All was well until I ran the 'make' command which then gave me a series of confusing errors. Appending  'make' with '-j 8' returns a different error rather than just 'make' as shown below.

make -j 8

```
Making all in expr
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__sch_istable", referenced from:
      _main in fixincl.o
      _initialize in fixincl.o
      _process in fixincl.o
      _char_macro_def_fix in fixfixes.o
      _char_macro_use_fix in fixfixes.o
      _format_fix in fixfixes.o
      _wrap_fix in fixfixes.o
      ...
  "__sch_toupper", referenced from:
      _wrap_fix in fixfixes.o
      _gnu_type_fix in fixfixes.o
  "_fdopen_unlocked", referenced from:
      _process in fixincl.o
      _load_file in fixincl.o
      _create_file in fixincl.o
      _proc2_fopen in procopen.o
  "_freopen_unlocked", referenced from:
      _main in fixincl.o
      _initialize in fixincl.o
  "_xcalloc", referenced from:
      _run_compiles in fixincl.o
      _run_shell in server.o
  "_xmalloc", referenced from:
      _process in fixincl.o
      _wrap_fix in fixfixes.o
      _run_shell in server.o
  "_xmalloc_set_program_name", referenced from:
      _initialize in fixincl.o
  "_xrealloc", referenced from:
      _run_shell in server.o
      _load_file_data in fixlib.o
  "_xregcomp", referenced from:
      _compile_re in fixlib.o
      _mn_get_regexps in fixlib.o
  "_xregerror", referenced from:
      _compile_re in fixlib.o
      _mn_get_regexps in fixlib.o
  "_xregexec", referenced from:
      _process in fixincl.o
      _machine_name_test in fixtests.o
      _char_macro_def_fix in fixfixes.o
      _char_macro_use_fix in fixfixes.o
      _format_fix in fixfixes.o
      _machine_name_fix in fixfixes.o
      _wrap_fix in fixfixes.o
      ...
  "_xstrdup", referenced from:
      _run_shell in server.o
  "_xstrerror", referenced from:
      _initialize in fixincl.o
      _process in fixincl.o
      _load_file in fixincl.o
      _create_file in fixincl.o
      _chain_open in procopen.o
      _load_file_data in fixlib.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [full-stamp] Error 1
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: *** [all-build-fixincludes] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Making all in tune
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in doc
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

make

```
checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp... no
configure: error: libgmp not found or uses a different ABI (including static vs shared).
Please read the INSTALL file -- see "In case of problem".
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-mpfr] Error 1
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Below is a list of things I've tried when compiling GCC (I'm new to compiling GCC so any help would be appreciated!)

- running 'make' with 'sudo'

Any help on resolving the errors would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You don't say what you did (was "this tutorial" supposed to be a link?), what exact commands you ran.

Comment: @Marc Glisse Yup, my bad, just added a hyperlink.